# Mechanical Turk command line tools suddenly not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, mechanicalturk

Running `loadHITs.sh` with the `-sandbox` flag has been working fine for several weeks. But suddenly, I'm getting this error:

```
...
  Start time: Thu Apr 02 21:47:20 PDT 2015
Error loading HITs: Error executing operation: Error #1 for RequestId: ab85a92a-5771-4b81-8b43-4e7a584c16b5 - AWS.NotYetImplemented: This method is not yet implemented (1428036440673 s)
com.amazonaws.mturk.service.exception.InternalServiceException: Error executing operation: Error #1 for RequestId: ab85a92a-5771-4b81-8b43-4e7a584c16b5 - AWS.NotYetImplemented: This method is not yet implemented (1428036440673 s)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.ErrorProcessingFilter.processErrors(ErrorProcessingFilter.java:158)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.ErrorProcessingFilter.execute(ErrorProcessingFilter.java:48)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.Filter.passMessage(Filter.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.RetryFilter.execute(RetryFilter.java:115)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.Filter.passMessage(Filter.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.CLTExceptionFilter.sendMessage(CLTExceptionFilter.java:77)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.CLTExceptionFilter.execute(CLTExceptionFilter.java:62)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.FilteredAWSService.executeRequests(FilteredAWSService.java:172)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.FilteredAWSService.executeRequest(FilteredAWSService.java:152)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.FilteredAWSService.executeRequest(FilteredAWSService.java:116)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterServiceRaw.registerHITType(RequesterServiceRaw.java:440)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterService.createHITs(RequesterService.java:1512)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.LoadHITs.loadHITs(LoadHITs.java:236)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.LoadHITs.runCommand(LoadHITs.java:120)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.AbstractCmd.run(AbstractCmd.java:148)
        at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.LoadHITs.main(LoadHITs.java:55)
```

The *exact same command* works fine if I omit the `-sandbox` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was on Amazon's end. Several other people [have been having the same problem](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=175226). The sandbox is now working normally.